# How to get video count and subscribers count of channels in search request?

Tags: kotlin, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am doing a search query where video, channels and playlists are displayed. The fact is that the search query does not provide full information about the channels or playlists.

[image]

This is how the query result looks like, as you see some fields come as null, and also the channel icon under the video is missing, how can I get these fields and display all this in one recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

With the YouTube Data API v3 [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) you can get `channelId` of channels and `videoId` of videos. Then to get more statistics about each you can use respectively [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) which both provided `id=channelId` and `id=videoId` will give you what you are interested in in the `statistics` answer field.

Comment: but how to combine all these queries in one recyclerview. I make a search request in this fragment Search and these requests should I also perform in this fragment?